# Javascipt Web Worker with Multiple Array Arguments

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I wish to pass two arrays to a JS Worker, process them in worker and reload the Page once the Processing is complete. However I am stuck with the Argument syntax. I am getting error : "**No function was found that matched the signature provided**"

```
var issueKeyArr = [1,2,3,3], executionIdArray = [4,5,5,6]
var myWorker = new Worker('zephyr-worker.js');

myWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('Message received from worker ========== reload the page here');
}

myWorker.postMessage(JSON.stringify(issueKeyArr), JSON.stringify(executionIdArray));
console.log('Message posted to worker');
```

My "zephyr-worker.js" file :

```
onmessage = function(issueKeyArr, executionIdArray) {   
    console.log("worker called ========================");
    for (var i=0; i < issueKeyArr.length; i++)
    {
        var issueKey = issueKeyArr[i];
        var executionId = executionIdArray[i];
        // more processing here...
    }
     postMessage("done");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [syntax of postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage) is

`worker.postMessage(yourMessageData, [transfer]);`

Since you don't need to really transfer any object ownership, you don't need to care about the optional `[transfer]` part of the `postMessage` signature above.

and the corresponding syntax of onmessage is

`myWorker.onmessage = function(messageEvent) { ... }`

with the `messageEvent` corresponding to an object that looks like `{..., data: yourMessageData, ...}`

Another thing that you can see from this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage) and the [example there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage#Example) is that you don't need to use JSON.stringify. Serialization of simple objects is already done automatically.

So your code should become:

```
var issueKeyArr = [1,2,3,3], executionIdArray = [4,5,5,6]
var myWorker = new Worker('zephyr-worker.js');

myWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('Message received from worker ========== reload the page here');
}

myWorker.postMessage({issueKeyArr: issueKeyArr, executionIdArray: executionIdArray});
console.log('Message posted to worker');
```

with your "zephyr-worker.js" file :

```
onmessage = function(messageEvent) {   
    console.log("worker called ========================");

    var issueKeyArr = message.data.issueKeyArr;
    var executionIdArray = message.data.executionIdArray;

    for (var i=0; i < issueKeyArr.length; i++)
    {
        var issueKey = issueKeyArr[i];
        var executionId = executionIdArray[i];
        // more processing here...
    }
     postMessage("done");
}
```

Comment: This one worked out well... Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a wrapper object, also no need to JSON.stringify, the structured serialization is now fast enough to let it do all the job.

So this would give

```
var issueKeyArr = [1,2,3,3], executionIdArray = [4,5,5,6]
var myWorker = new Worker('zephyr-worker.js');

myWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('Message received from worker ========== reload the page here');
}

myWorker.postMessage( { issueKeyArr, executionIdArray } );
console.log('Message posted to worker');
```

And in the worker

```
onmessage = function( { data: { issueKeyArr, executionIdArray } } ) {   
    console.log("worker called ========================");
    for (var i=0; i < issueKeyArr.length; i++)
    {
        var issueKey = issueKeyArr[i];
        var executionId = executionIdArray[i];
        // more processing here...
    }
     postMessage("done");
}
```

```js
const worker_script = `
onmessage = function( { data: { issueKeyArr, executionIdArray } } ) {   
    console.log("worker called ========================");
    for (var i=0; i < issueKeyArr.length; i++)
    {
        var issueKey = issueKeyArr[i];
        var executionId = executionIdArray[i];
        // more processing here...
    }
     postMessage("done");
}`;
const worker_blob = new Blob([worker_script], { type: "text/javascript" });
const worker_url = URL.createObjectURL(worker_blob);


var issueKeyArr = [1,2,3,3], executionIdArray = [4,5,5,6]
var myWorker = new Worker(worker_url);

myWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('Message received from worker ========== reload the page here');
}

myWorker.postMessage( { issueKeyArr, executionIdArray } );
console.log('Message posted to worker');
```

Comment: Thank you for the Code snippet.. This really helped.

since 'francis duvivier' answer explained receiving and processing the arrays in the Worker I am accepting that answer..